# Diffucult Tautology to Prove

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to show that the following is a tautology:

> $(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \Rightarrow (q \vee r)$

Can anyone help, as far as I can get is to the following:

> $[(\neg p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge \neg r)] \vee (q \vee r)$

Comment: Depends on what logical axioms are your base.

Comment: Consider what if $p$ is true. Consider what if $p$ is false. (Someone said to use $q$ instead, but I think that using $p$ is easier.)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple and clean way to do this is to write a table with all the possibillities.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
   & \text{p} & \text{not }p &  q & r\\ \hline
  1&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true}\\
  2&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{true} & \text{false}\\
  3&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{false} & \text{true}\\
  4&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{false} & \text{false}\\
  5&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true} & \text{true}\\
  6&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true} & \text{false}\\
  7&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{false} & \text{true}\\
  8&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{false} & \text{false}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Now you impose the conditions. Firstly $(p \text{ or } q)$ mean we can remove line 7 and 8 (since both $p$ and $q$ are false there so they are not cases we are interested in). Secondly $(\text{not } p \text{ or } r)$ means we can strike line 2 and line 4. You are then left with

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
   & \text{p} & \text{not }p &  q & r\\ \hline
  1&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true}\\
  3&\text{true} & \text{false} & \text{false} & \text{true}\\
  5&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true} & \text{true}\\
  6&\text{false} & \text{true} & \text{true} & \text{false}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

We have now shown that $(p \text{ or } q)$ and $(\text{not } p \text{ or } r)$ implies that one of the possibillities above apply. Compare this with what you are trying to prove. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose “$p$ or $q$” and “not $p$ or $r$” are true. We need to show that “$q$ or $r$” is true.

Case 1: $q$ is true. Then we're done.

Case 2: $q$ is not true. In order to show “$q$ or $r$,” we must prove that $r$ is true. Now, since $q$ is not true but “$p$ or $q$” is, it follows that $p$ is true. Now, “not $p$ or $r$” is true, but “not $p$” is not true (since $p$ is true), so it must be the case that $r$ is true, as required.

Comment: It would, I think, have been much better to leave a hint like "consider the two cases $q$ and not-$q$" than to simply do this person's homework for him.

Comment: It's actually easier to consider the cases $p$ and not $p$. If $p$,  then $r$, then $q$ or $r$. If not $p$, then $q$ then $q$ or $r$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Proposition.** In the Boolean domain, the following is a tautology: $$(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \Rightarrow (q \vee r)$$

*Proof.*

- If $p = 1$, then the formula becomes $r \Rightarrow q \vee r$, which is clearly true.
- If $p = 0$, then the formula becomes $q \Rightarrow q \vee r$, which is clearly true.