# Examples of the use of $(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \Rightarrow (q \vee r)$ in "real" mathematics?

Tags: logic, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916481/42339), a proof is requested for the following tautology: $$(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \Rightarrow (q \vee r)$$

Its pretty easy to prove; nonetheless, I don't find the formula at all intuitive, and I'd be impressed if this has been used to prove things in "real" mathematics.

> **Question.** Are there any theorems $\Phi$ belonging to mathematics proper (e.g. number theory, groups, rings, real analysis, linear algebra, graph theory, etc.) such that $\Phi$ is most easily proved using this tautology?

I fundamentally have no idea how to tag this question.

Comment: Would you find it more intuitive when rendered as $(\neg p\to q), (p\to r) \vdash q\lor r$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, oh, wow. Yes. That's completely obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think of $p \vee q$ as equivalent to $\neg p \implies q$ and $\neg p \vee r$ as equivalent to $p \implies r$, this is used all the time, whenever you have a result that has two cases.